# Test To Determine If Two Circles Intersect In A 2-D Plane

Tags: geometry

Given two circles described by the 3-tuples (x-coordinates, y-coordinates, radius) I read on StackOverflow that if the following inequality holds, then the two circles intersect:

$$(r_0 - r_1)^2 \leq (x_0 - x_1)^2 + (y_0 - y_1)^2 \leq (r_0 + r_1)^2$$

Intersection is defined as two circles having at least one common point. I wrote a computer program to apply this result to a list of circles to see which pairs of circles intersect and I am getting the wrong results. For example, the solution says that the following circles $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,1,5)$ do have at least one common point and so are defined as intersecting, but the above inequality gives :

$$16 \leq 1 \leq 36$$

which is not true and so the circles are not marked as intersecting.

My question is whether the above inequality is a correct test to determine if two circles intersect? If not, then what is the correct geometric way to determine this.

Comment: I would not say that these circles intersect. Try to draw them. One of them is inside the other.

Comment: these are concentric circles. Give me a sec to write a condition.

Comment: @m0nhawk, my solution may be an amalgamation of the inequality in the post that you reference and also the inequality I have listed in my post.

Comment: I don't see a common point on the circles. Or does "common point" include the points _inside_ the circles?

Comment: @DavidK, I've updated the post. It's not the same question as the proposed as being a duplicate to this post. In fact, I need to avoid the case where the circles completely overlap.

Comment: I agree it is not a duplicate. I still do not know know what the question really is. I would say that "have at least one common point" is exactly the _definition_ of "intersect", so I think there must be something a bit different you have in mind. Perhaps you mean that the circles intersect _or_ one is entirely inside the other?

Comment: @DavidK, I have updated the post to make the question more clearer.

Comment: @DavidK, Found the solution in this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/39561/124485

Answer (score 0):

These are inside each other. you can tell by the centers and the radii.
 This condition should be true where the sum of the radii is greater than the distance.

This checks for intersection.

That is to say they will intersect iff $ \sqrt{(x_{2}-x_{1})^{2} + (y_{2}-y_{1})^{2}} \geq {r_{1}+r_{2}}$

If they are equal, they meet at a point $(x,y)$.
If the LHS is greater than the right hand side, the circles will cut at at least 1 point, and have a least one common point.

where $(x_{1},y_{1})$ is the center of circle $1$, and $r_{1}$ is the radius of circle 1.

and $(x_{2},y_{2})$ is the center of circle $2$, and $r_{2}$ is the radius of circle $2$.

This checks for one circle having at least one point in the other circle

Take the magnitude of the vector $ \sqrt{(x)^{2} + (y)^{2} + (r^{2})} \leq \sqrt{X^{2} + Y^{2} + {R^{2}}}$

where r is the radius of the smaller circle and R is the radius of the larger circle, and the left side refers to the smaller circle and the right side refers to the larger circle.

Comment: I have re-read the problem statement and there is an additional condition. The problem is to find all circles which intersect and those which have at least one common point. So the concentric circles satisfy the latter condition.

Comment: Updated the answer to take care of both situations.

Comment: I will code this up and check the results. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the post to make the question clearer. The first inequality does not regard the circles mentioned in my question as intersecting. But it is clear they do have a common point. I need you to provide the subscripts for the LHS of the second inequality in order to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, the solution says that the following circles (0,0,1) and (0,1,5) intersect, but the program does not flag these circles as such due to the above inequality i.e.:

$16≤1≤36$

why does it says that these intersect? 16 is not less than 1 and 36 is not greater than 1. The program and equations are correct.You can also see that they don't intersect(meet or cut at a point).

Comment: I've updated my post. For these concentric circles, they should be flagged as having at least one common point, which they obviously do. There's two qualifying criteria to flag a pair of circles: 1) that the circles intersect and/or 2) they have at least one common point.