# Finding coordinate equations for graphing of problem.

Tags: geometry

Have a request to help me in draw using desmos the "Treasure hunt problem" (explained in detail with basic approaches [here](http://journals.tc-library.org/index.php/matheducation/article/view/984) with desired implementation as in basic option given [here](http://dynamicmathematicslearning.com/treasure-hunt.html).

I expect that the best approach is to have two circles tangentially intersecting each other, and their centers representing 'Pine' and 'Oak' trees respectively; while the intersection of two circles being the location of 'gallows'. Also, the each circles' two radius are perpendicular to each other. The other end on the perpendicular radii represents 'Spike1', 'Spike2' respectively.

I  request some help in finding the intersection point of two circles that represents the gallows, as the main issue is this configuration is not workable , i.e. the intersection of two circles is meaningless once the relative angle among the pine and oak trees (the two radii) is changed.

[image]
The only way is for the two circles to be intersecting still, but be able to to move while intersecting at more than one point possibly, as in the below diagram.[image] 
Anyway, the approach should ensure the independence of treasure from the position of the gallows, as shown in the first link. also, may be for the above approach using circles, polar coordinates' equations may work to represent using coordinate geometry in desmos.

 Would prefer the circle based approach, as above.

An alternate approach as shown in the first link also, is to place the trees on the x-axis, with gallows changing location along the locus of some parametric equation as a function of distance from the trees.

In the first approach, the movement of gallows is not possible, and only a particular configuration can be shown like in the first / second diagrams, while in the second approach (as shown in the third diagram, below) the gallows moves as a function on locus.

The second approach is shown below:[image]

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: @JohnGlenn Want to plot graph with independent points' coordinates  changing to all possible set of values, in desmos. Not clear, but polar equation would be easy if circle approach is taken.

Comment: By "changing to all set of values" you mean an interactive model of the problem?

Comment: Yes, as given in the second link for the 'basic' approach. Want a model to work, and circle seemed the right choice, and polar coordinates may serve. For the second approach by placing the trees on x - axis, have no clue.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the approach you want?

Comment: @JohnGlenn I hope have edited to accommodate both approaches, while emphasizing the first approach (based on circles). Although would love solution by both, as second approach is totally unapproachable.

Comment: I don't really know what desmos does or is, but I have the impression that you are using the graphing features of desmos? Why not use the [geometry tool](https://www.desmos.com/geometry)?

Comment: I have always liked the complex analysis approach to this problem.

Comment: The very first approach, with the circles tangent, doesn’t adequately model the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Still not sure what you are after, though, but I have constructed the model using functions in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9hlnmyarpk)

---

So you have circles defined by:
$$\begin{align}\left(x-h_1\right)^2+\left(y-k_1\right)^2=r_1^2\tag{1}\\
\left(x-h_2\right)^2+\left(y-k_2\right)^2=r_2^2\tag{2}\end{align}$$
Where $(1)$'s center is the **Oak**$(h_1,k_1)$ and $(2)$'s center is the **Pine**$(h_2,k_2)$.

The location of the Gallows is defined by $(G_x,G_y)$, of course the radii of $(1)$ and $(2)$ are defined by:
$$r_1=\sqrt{\left(G_x-h_1\right)^2+\left(G_y-k_1\right)^2}\\r_2=\sqrt{\left(G_x-h_2\right)^2+\left(G_y-k_2\right)^2}\\
$$

The lines connecting Oak and Pine to Gallows are defined by:
$$y-k_1=\left(M_1\right)\left(x-h_1\right)\\y-k_2=\left(M_2\right)\left(x-h_2\right)\\
$$
Where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are the slopes of the respective lines. Of course, to get the $90^\circ$ turn, the perpendicular lines equations will be the same as above except the slopes are the negative reciprocal, thus:
$$\begin{align}
y-k_1&=-\left(M_1\right)^{-1}\left(x-h_1\right)\tag{3}\\
y-k_2&=-\left(M_2\right)^{\left(-1\right)}\left(x-h_2\right)\tag{4}\\
\end{align}$$

To find the **Spikes**, you just have to find the intersection between $(1)$ & $(3)$, and $(2)$ & $(3)$, thus you get:
$$\begin{align}\text{$(1)$ & $(3)$}\iff (K_x,K_y)&\Rightarrow K_x=\frac{h_1M_1^2+h_1+\sqrt{M_1^2+1}M_1r_1}{M_1^2+1}\\
&\Rightarrow K_y=\frac{k_1M_1^2+k_1-\sqrt{M_1^2+1}r_1}{M_1^2+1}\\
\text{$(2)$ & $(4)$}\iff (P_x,P_y)&\Rightarrow P_x=\frac{h_2M_2^2+h_2+\sqrt{M_2^2+1}M_2r_2}{M_2^2+1}\\
&\Rightarrow P_y=\frac{k_2M_2^2+k_2-\sqrt{M_2^2+1}r_2}{M_2^2+1}
\end{align}$$

Thus, simply, the **Treasure** is the midpoint between $(K_x,K_y)$ and $(P_x,P_y)$, which should be:
$$M_{P,K}=\left(\frac{P_x+K_x}{2},\frac{P_y+K_y}{2}\right)$$

---

If you want the two circles tangent at the **Gallows**$(G_x,G_y)$, then you have to make the Oak, Pine and Gallows collinear, say by lying in the $x$-axis. You can freely move the Gallows then across the $x$-axis. And as mentioned in the first link, the Treasure is invariant to the location of the Gallows.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the implementation of the first diagram. I am trying to make the implementation of the second diagram, so that the gallows is  stationary but the trees can move in y-axis.

Comment: @jiten The one I made in Desmos allows you to move all points, i.e. the Oak, Gallows and Pine

Comment: Please help resolve my doubts in answer: The equation ($1$) & ($3$) would yield 

Please help resolve my doubts in answer: The equation ($1$) & ($3$) would yield 

the Spike$1$ (for Pine) coordinates, denoted as $K_x, K_y$. To get $K_y$, need get from ($3$) in terms of $x-h_1\,\, (=-(M_1)(y-k_1))$ to substitute in ($1$), to get the coordinates of Spike$1$ as : $(1+(M_1)^2)(K_y-k_1)^2=r_1^2\implies K_y=k_1+\frac{r_1}{\sqrt{1+(M_1)^2}}$. This expression can be further transformed to:$K_y=\frac{k_1M_1^2+k_1+r_1\sqrt{1+(M_1)^2}}{1+(M_1)^2}$. But, minus sign for term $r_1\sqrt{}$ is not got.

Comment: How to specify that the two circles intersect is not clear. As specifying $abs(r_1-r_2)\le \sqrt{(h_1-h_2)^2 + (k_1-k_2)^2}\le (r_1+r_2)$ is also not helping. I have got a graph, from Wolfram,  at : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gu4wjdfm1o that covers all possible cases of intersection of two circles; but the issue is still complex. One issue I feel is that when there are two intersection points, then which one to specify as the 'gallows'. Also, the value $d$ is to be prespecified in a range, which is also not the desired feature. Our graph is much more complex comparatively.

Comment: Request suggestions for why my graph below is not at all like your working graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xq4qmiqskt. Have put condition at $19$ to enable the circles to intersect as read at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/456310/424260. This condition was earlier the one stated in the earlier comment, but did not work; as also for this condition. Also, do not know how to get 'gallows'  plotted.

Comment: If you could please help by editing your answer to specify the intersection condition of two circles, then would be highly thankful. I am feeling helpless at that, as am unable to put anything working for that. Any use of your answer is contingent on having the circles 'always' intersect; without that it is all waste.

Comment: @jiten don't you think the circles centered at Pine and Oak should always intersect? If the Gallows must lie on the two circles, then your guaranteed to have at least an intersection.

Comment: Based on my understanding of the problem, the circles ensure that you travel the same distance perpendicular to your first path. I do not see a solution where the circles never touch.

Comment: As for the intersection of the circles, there was no use to solve them mathematically, as one would always be the Gallows, and the other has no apparent use to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If we put the Oak tree at A, and the Pine tree at B, and your starting point at X.

And we plot it in the complex plane.

Then spike 1 is at $A + i(A-X)$ 
And spike 2 is at $B - i(A-X)$

Putting the treasure at $\frac {A+B}{2} + \frac {A-B}{2} i$
And clearly the location of the treasure does not depend on $X.$